# Auto installer for vps

Tags: server, clone, custom-installer

Scenario is:

1. I have a vps running ubuntu having nginx and other stuff
2. I want to make it into an autoinstaller and probably save it online somewhere, so that it can be accessed via curl, wget, apt-get (dunno how to set it though), but whatever way
3. so when I'm on a new vps, or i refresh my os by reinstalling it on the same server, I simply autoinstall everything as it was for both: same server, or on any other server
4. yes I know if the other server has different domain name or ip, i will edit that from settings and stuff then, but the query is how to simply make a clone type package of it.
5. query is regarding clone other than os itself

Waiting anxiously for answers from anyone who can point me in the right direction!

Note: I don't need a bash script, as it will install the fresh packages, I want to get my modified ones on the new server!

Comment: You can make a bash script.

Comment: any help in right direction please? how to create it?

Comment: You can make a bash script that can install all of your packages for you. I can show you an example if you want?

Comment: yes please show me an example :)

Comment: sorry issue still not solved, I updated the question with more details

Answer (score 2):

Create a file called setup.sh and make something that looks like this. Obviously add the packages that you want to install. Then you can run the script by doing `sudo sh /path/to/script`.

**Note:** I am using `aptitude install` instead of `apt-get install` but you can use either one.

```shell
#/bin/bash

# Updates Repo #
####################
sudo aptitude update
####################

# Upgrades The System #
########################
sudo aptitude upgrade -y
########################

# Mysql #
########################################################
sudo aptitude install mysql-server libmysqlclient-dev -y
########################################################

# Zip and Unzip #
###################################
sudo aptitude install zip unzip -y
###################################

# SMART #
######################################
sudo aptitude install smartmontools -y
######################################

# Webmin #
######################################################################
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
sudo touch Webmin.list
sudo printf 'deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib
deb http://webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk/repository sarge contrib' > Webmin.list
sudo chown root: Webmin.list
sudo chmod 644 Webmin.list
cd /root
sudo wget http://www.webmin.com/jcameron-key.asc
sudo apt-key add jcameron-key.asc
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude upgrade -y
sudo aptitude install webmin -y
#######################################################################

# Dependencies for Ruby #
#####################################################
sudo aptitude install openssl curl git-core nodejs -y
#####################################################

# Imagemagick #
####################################
sudo aptitude install imagemagick -y
####################################

# Apache #
############################################
sudo aptitude install apache2 apache2-dev -y
############################################

# Networking #
######################################
sudo aptitude install ifenslave-2.6 -y
######################################

# Passenger #
#######################################################################
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 561F9B9CAC40B2F7
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
touch Passenger.list
sudo printf 'deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger trusty main' > Passenger.list
sudo chown root: Passenger.list
sudo chmod 644 Passenger.list
cd /root
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install libapache2-mod-passenger -y
sudo a2enmod passenger
sudo service apache2 restart
#######################################################################

# Samba #
##############################
sudo aptitude install samba -y
##############################
```

Comment: and can i save it online and call it through url? how to do that then? curl?

Comment: @nabtron You can put it on [Github](https://github.com/) or a cloud service such as [Google Dive](https://drive.google.com/) or [Onedrive](https://onedrive.live.com/) and then use wget to download it from the cloud service.

Comment: @nabtron If you do put it on a cloud service you have to make the file public so that you can download it via wget.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a example of a bash script  that I think will help solve your problem.

First setup a folder/file structure that looks something like this:

- Setup [This is a folder]

  - Setup.sh [This is a file]
  - apache.conf [This is a file]

Run the `Setup.sh` file by doing `sudo sh /path/to/Setup.sh` after you customise the `apache2.conf file`

**Setup.sh**

```
# Install apache2 for this example
sudo apt-get install apache2 -y

# Change the default config file to your custom one
cat apache.conf > /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

**apache2.conf**

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: "NGINX and other stuff" means apache2?  Or are you using this as an example here?

Comment: @ThomasW. Yes if you wanted to use Niginx then you would exchange all of the apache2 stuff for Niginx.

Comment: this is awesome and well in right direction :) Thanks!

but can't i do something by just doing "wget" to my stuff?

Comment: @nabtron you could put that folder and it's contents on a cloud service provider so that you could download the files when you need them with wget **Note: you have to make the folder public so that you can download it**

Comment: so its files will replace all the previous files if they are on the server too?

Comment: @nabtron Yes it will.